# Which user settings.xml is getting with user directory mapped to a remote unit?

Tags: maven, encryption, maven-3, settings

I'm having issues by creating password. I think it is caused by having mapped the user directory to a remote unit.

**settings.xml**

```
...
<proxy>
   <id>myproxy</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <username>username</username>
   <password>{NG9kNfX1DQAHKQeA4ksUpLJvr2EzWWgGSHSZVE/T/sU=}</password>
   <host>rproxy.url.com</host>
   <port>3128</port>
   <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
...
```

**A) Maven directory**

c:/dev/apache-maven-3.6.3

**B) Maven default directory**

c:/users/username

**C) Maven mapped user directory**

h:

Where should I keep my user configuration files? Must I duplicate on B) and C)? Which file is getting?

If I keep my files only on A) settings.xml and settings-security.xml
when I execute mvn --encrypt-password

```
λ mvn --encrypt-password
Password:
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: h:\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
[ERROR] Caused by: h:\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

If I keep my files only on B) settings.xml and settings-security.xml
when I execute mvn --encrypt-password

```
λ mvn --encrypt-password
Password:
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: h:\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
[ERROR] Caused by: h:\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

If I keep my files only on C) settings.xml and settings-security.xml
when I execute mvn --encrypt-password

```
λ mvn --encrypt-password
Password:
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\e43102790p\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\e43102790p\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
[ERROR] Caused by: C:\Users\e43102790p\.m2\settings-security.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

And If I keep my files on B) and C) settings.xml and settings-security.xml
when I execute mvn --encrypt-password works but when I try to compile -U

```
...
HTTP proxy server authentication failed ...
407 Proxy Authentication Required
...
```

Answer (score 0):

By default maven use your home dir to find settings.xml, if your %HOMEPATH% is different in different setups - yes, settings.xml will be resolved to different files.

To avoid config duplication you can pass `-s` option to maven to set concrete settings.xml
file. You can type this option every time, or add it e.g. to mvn.bat, or create alias (I'm not sure however, if windows support aliases))